# Error when trying to save read-only Excel file through C# Interop

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, interop

I'd like to save a password-protected Excel file in WPF with 1 cell altered through `Microsoft Interop`.

What I've tried to do, is to open the Excel-file wit the read-only mode disabled. 
I tried achieving it by writing the following piece of code:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilename, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing,
                password, password, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

> Please ignore any security issues involving the password, as this code is purely for illustrative purposes.

The third parameter in the `.Open()` method specifies the `ReadOnly` object, which is set to false. 
The seventh parameter in the `.Open()` method specifies the `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended` object, which is set to true. 
By doing this I would have thought that the Excel-document would open without the read-only mode enabled, but it does not.

I also disabled the Excel alerts that normally are displayed to the user, by writing the following code:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Every time I run this piece of code:

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(excelFilename);
```

I get the following Exception: 
`system.runtime.interopservices.comexception 'cannot access read-only document...'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

If you're using Excel 2019 (not sure about other versions) try this:

Open the Excel file -> go on the "Review" tab of the ribbon menu -> select "Share Workbook" -> **CHECK** "Use the old shared workbooks feature instead of the new co-authoring experience".

In my case, this solved the problem.

I think this is one of the many drawbacks of using Office Interop.
If you can choose, I would advice you not to use it, as one day or another you'll have other problems of this kind if not worse.